# asp.net web api 2 route No HTTP resource was found

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

**IDE**: Visual Studio 2017

**Project**: Web Application

`WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Streets",
    routeTemplate: "api/Streets/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controler = "Streets",
        id = RouteParameter.Optional,
     }
);
```

Here is the `Get` action in `Streets` controller, which is the only action modified. Other actions are not changed. The controller is scaffold as `Web API 2 Controller with read, write actions`.

```
// GET: api/Streets
public DataPack Get()
{
    DataPack pack = new DataPack();

    ...

    return pack;
}
```

**Tool**: Postman

**Method**: GET

**Uri**: api/Streets

**Status**: 404 Not Found

**Message**: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50166/api/Streets'."

**MessageDetail**: "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:50166/api/Streets'"

Please let me know if there's any mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in the route declaration, it should be

```
defaults: new
{
    controller = "Streets", //you wrote controler
    id = RouteParameter.Optional,
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this world's most difficult error:) However, the other routes with the same spelling mistake works properly, and I copied from those code.